# java - keycloak cannot get user principal

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

Recently, I use keycloak for securing some endpoints of my api. I want to leave the rest insecure, so it can be accessed both logged in user and anonymous user. But I want to get user principal for the logged in user. I try to get Authorizarion header for getting user data but I think this is not a good way. Or should I create guest account on keycloak and securing all of my endpoints.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I just use keycloak adapter for this pattern
`/api/v1/secure/*`.
But i want to get username if Authorization header exist for `/api/v1/*`.

I try this

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/hello")
@ResponseBody
public String hello(Principal principal) {
  return "hello " + principal.getName();
}
```

and throw `NullPointerException` but it's work when I use `/api/v1/secure/hello`.

Comment: How are you interacting with Keycloak?  Do you just have a JWT or do you have an adapter in your application server?

Comment: I have an adapter in my apps but it just covers some url patterns. I have problem to get user information for other url patterns.

Comment: Hello, please post your code. Which adapter do you use?

Comment: Hi, I updated my post and  add some codes, hope you can help.

Comment: If you don't secure your URL with the keycloak adapter (cf. your pattern) or any application server's security constraint/method then you will not get a Principal nor a KeycloakSecurityContext. You need to code yourself (or mix up available tools to do) the parsing and interpretation of the authorization and tokens if present in requests.